# Find feature categories associated with a specific target category

Tags: machine-learning, correlation

I have a Dataset with three columns.

[image: Dataset]

Products (up to 200).
The quality checks that have not been conducted at the final quality check. (Up to 70 different Quality Control Measures)
The result of the quality check.

My target is to identify those Checks that are correlating with BAD end results meaning that they should have been conducted. I am assuming though, that it is not necceseraily a single one but rather a combination of x Quality Measures.

So for example the result could be. These are the critical Quality Checks that once they are open (in this combination) they lead to a bad result:
Q1
Q2 + Q7
Q3 + Q8 + Q20

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: This is also an [inverse classification problem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11390-010-9337-x)

Comment: In the linked paper is described a method to construct inverted statistics which can be useful to your case, check it out

Answer (score 0):

One option is to look at the set membership information associated with "BAD" target value.

Which quality numbers are only associated with that label? Which quality numbers are never associated with that label? Which quality numbers are associated with that label and other labels?